# variable in the sql nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, vue.js, request

Hello y need send variable in my request sql.
For searching value in my database

```
var cent = "search";
con.connect(function (err) {
if (err) throw err;
var sql ="SELECT * FROM cadito.activitys WHERE description like ?";
//Send an array with value(s) to replace the escaped values:
con.query(sql, [%cen%], function (err, result) {
    console.log(global.re = JSON.stringify((result)));
});

});
```

My problème syntaxe error.

Thank for help me.

My log db_conn.js:20
con.query(sql, [%cent%], function (err, result) {
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '%'
?[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)?[39m
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)?[39m
?[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47?[39m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out to use `%` inside the sql string and remove it from the params :

```
var cent = "search";
con.connect(function (err) {
if (err) throw err;
var sql ="SELECT * FROM cadito.activitys WHERE description like %?%";
//Send an array with value(s) to replace the escaped values:
con.query(sql, [cent], function (err, result) {
    console.log(global.re = JSON.stringify((result)));
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

i found another issue in my question
just placed % in my request and concaten my variable with %

```
var cent = "search";
con.connect(function (err) {
if (err) throw err;
var sql ="SELECT * FROM cadito.activitys WHERE description like ?";
//Send an array with value(s) to replace the escaped values:
con.query(sql, ['%'+cent+'%'], function (err, result) {
    console.log(global.re = JSON.stringify((result)));
});

});
```

working for me